# The use of WITH (ROWLOCK) in Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a .NET workflow application being used by 100 users on a daily basis. This workflow refers to a table where the workflow status ID is getting updated. The update statement is using `rowlock`.

My update statement in SP:

```
update table1 set statuid = a.statId from table2 a with (rowlock) where  ID = @ids
```

My question is: does this update really requires a `rowlock`? Doesn't the DB can handle this automatically?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server handles this automatically -- the difference being that `ROWLOCK` forces the engine to always issue individual row locks, even if it would otherwise choose to escalate to page or table locks when a very large number of rows needs to be updated. This may help or hinder performance, depending on the scenario -- or it may have no effect at all, if there are never enough rows updated to make lock escalation necessary.

Comment: Sorry difficult to understand. So I have Edited my question with an example. Anything in simple please?

Comment: Assuming `ID` is a unique key or otherwise has an index, yes, the `ROWLOCK` is unnecessary -- the engine will only ever have to seek to a single row and lock that for the update, there's no need to explicitly specify that. This may be leftover cargo cult programming from when adding it helped at one point for some update statement.

Comment: The simplest answer is that using query hints is something you should do **only** when you have tried everything else **and** you can explain and justify clearly why it is needed. If either of those things are not true then you should avoid using query hints for that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `rowlock` in this situation.

```
update table1 set statuid = a.statId from table2 a where ID = @ids
```

But, your example SQL statement assumes there is only 1 value for `statId` in `table2`.

**EDIT**:

You said in the comments:

> there can be multiple values in statuid in table2. However the ids is unique at given point of time

I still don't think `rowlock` is necessary, but for safety you should take the max of the id from table2.

```
update table1 set statuid = (select max(statId) from table2) where ID = @ids
```

Comment: I'm updating the table 1 by taking table 2 value ( there can be multiple values in  statuid in table 2). However the ids is unique at given point of time. Do you still think rowlock is necessary?

Comment: I'm updating the table 1 by taking table 2 value ( there can be multiple values in statuid in table 2). However the ids is unique at given point of time. Do you still think rowlock is necessary? More over, is there any ways to examine or trace this? Please note that, with this implementation I gauss things are working sometimes and sometime Not. Workflow status is sometimes updating and sometimes not. So how can I be 100% sure to before implementing this or removing the rowlock? Thanks.

Comment: See edits to answer. You seem very concerned about this, almost as is you are not certain that the "ids is unique at given point of time". It not `rowlock` you should be concerned about, but your shaky design. If you want to examine or trace, you can use the debugger or use variables to examine interim values.